# How to match a string and print the next word afterthat?

Tags: tcl

Lets say i have the following script and have to look for `.model` and print the next two word before `(`. The following is the contents of the file that I need to read.

```
    .model Q2N2222  NPN(Is=14.34f Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Vaf=74.03 Bf=255.9 Ne=1.307
                        Ise=14.34f Ikf=.2847 Xtb=1.5 Br=6.092 Nc=2 Isc=0 Ikr=0 Rc=1
+       Cjc=7.306p Mjc=.3416 Vjc=.75 Fc=.5 Cje=22.01p Mje=.377 Vje=.75
+       Tr=46.91n Tf=411.1p Itf=.6 Vtf=1.7 Xtf=3 Rb=10)
*       National    pid=19      case=TO18
*       88-09-07 bam    creation
*$
    .model Q2N3904  NPN(Is=6.734f Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Vaf=74.03 Bf=416.4 Ne=1.259
    .model Q2N3906  PNP(Is=1.41f Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Vaf=18.7 Bf=180.7 Ne=1.5 Ise=0
```

Here is the code i have written so far. But i couldnt get any. Need the help

```
proc find_lib_parts {f_name} {
    set value [string first ".lib" $f_name]
    if {$value != -1} {
        #open the file
        set fid [ open $f_name "r"]

        #read the fid and split it in to lines
        set infos [split [read $fid] "\n"]
        close $fid

        set res {}
        append res "MODEL FOUND:\n"
    
        if {[llength $line] > 2 && [lindex $line 0] eq {model}} {
            #lappend res [lindex $data 2] \n 
            lappend res [split $line "("]\n
        } 
        if {[llength $line] > 2 && [lindex $line 0] eq {MODEL}} {
            #lappend res [lindex $data 2] \n 
            lappend res [split $line "("]\n
        }
    }

    return $res
```

Comment: `regexp {\.model (\w+) (\w+)(?=\()} $line -> word1 word2`?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a regular expression is by far the simplest way of doing such a search. Assuming the words are always on the same line, it's easy:

```
proc find_lib_parts {f_name} {
    set fid [open $f_name]
    set infos [split [read $fid] "\n"]
    close $fid

    set found {}
    foreach line $infos {
        if {[regexp {\.model\s+(\w+\s+\w+)\(} $line -> twoWords]} {
            lappend found $twoWords
        }
    }
    return $found
}
```

For your input data sample, that'll produce a result like this:

```
{Q2N2222  NPN} {Q2N3904  NPN} {Q2N3906  PNP}
```

If there's nothing to find, you'll get an empty list. (I assume you pass filenames correctly anyway, so I omitted that check.)

---

The regular expression, which should virtually always be enclosed in `{`braces`}` in Tcl, is this:

```
\.model\s+(\w+\s+\w+)\(
```

It's relatively simple. The pieces of it are:

1. `\.model` — literal “`.model`” (with an escape of the `.` because it is a RE metacharacter)
2. `\s+` — some whitespace
3. `(` — start a capturing group (the bit we put into the `twoWords` variable)
4. `\w+` — a “word”, one or more alphanumeric (or underscore) characters
5. `\s+` — some whitespace
6. `\w+` — a “word”, one or more alphanumeric (or underscore) characters
7. `)` — end of the capturing group
8. `\(` — literal “`(`”, escaped

The `regexp` command matches this, returning whether or not it matched (effectively boolean without the `-all` option, which we're not using here), and assigning the various groups to the variables named afterwards, `->` for the whole matched string (yes, that's a legal variable name; I like to use it for `regexp` variables that dump info I don't want) and `twoWords` for the interesting substring.

Comment: Regular expressions are a powerful tool for simple parsing. In this case, they let us do both the match of the string and the extract of the interesting bit in one step. The trick to a good RE is to _keep it simple._ Very complicated REs are possible, but almost impossible to understand and debug…